# String Counting / Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

For a string of length $n\ge 1$ and the characters $a$, $b$, and $c$, how many strings can be formed of length $n$ if the character $a$ must occur an even number of times?

I understand that we need to take the base case and then subtract the false situations, but I cannot figure out how you would calculate the false situations.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I first calculated the case with no exceptions. To calculate the situations where the exclusion isn't true I tried to add up all the different even ways you could do it up until n, but I had no luck figuring out how to deal with a different remainder each time.

Comment: Do you know how to set up a recurrence? Or are you supposed to only solve it via "take the base case and subtract the false situations"?

Comment: A recurrence would be fine yes, I'm not too familiar with writing them however but I do understand them.

Answer (score 2):

Let the strings of length $n$ with an even number of $a$ be $E_n$.
Let the strings of length $n$ with an odd number of $a$ be $O_n$.

We have $ E_n + O_n = 3^n$,
$E_{n} = O_{n-1} + 2E_{n-1} $,
$O_{n} = 2O_{n-1} + E_{n-1}$

Can you take it from here?